# How to go from Tree to Total orders

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, trees

Given a tree $T=(X,E)$, is it guaranteed for any orientation of the edges $E$, there exist a strict total order preserves it?

For instance, let $X=\{x_1,x_2,..x_n\}$ and $E=(x_i,x_{i+1})$ the result is a tree $T$. Let $G$ be directed graph of $T$ (add directions into the set of edges in $T$). is it always the case where there is a total order $\succ$ extend/equals $G$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by induction on the number of nodes. It is clearly true if there is just one node. In general, remove a leaf node, order the remaining tree, and insert the leaf node in the order. There is only a single constraint to be satisfied in doing so, and it is trivially satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every order can be extended to a total order by the [Szilprajn extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szpilrajn_extension_theorem).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here, by *every order* you mean every possible directed graph (DAG) of the orientation of the edges? Also, Can I say that every possible orientation of $T$ will result in a DAG and every DAG has a topological ordering (total ordering)?

Comment: By order, I mean a partial order. A tree can be seen as partial order on the set of edges. It doesn't work with every directed graph, since cycles cause problems. But there are no cycles in the tree.

Comment: Thanks. How about my naive solution: every orientation result in a DAG (partial order) and every DAG has a topological ordering (total order).. does it make sense?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "every DAG has a topological ordering (total order)"?

Comment: Every DAG can be extended to a total order by topological sorting. I am not mathematician but this is what I know. Please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: That should be correct. I just had to look up the terminology you used.